# How do I change the file location of images taken with Windows + Shift + S?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

It is a pain to hit Windows + Prt sc to take a screenshot and have to crop them all afterward when I can use Windows + Shift + S to have the image how I want it, but it's stored in a temporary file that is a pain to get to. How do I change it to go directly into my screenshots folder?